# How to connect to discovered Bluetooth device with android java

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have a code in Android Java that scans for Bluetooth devices in range and if any is discovered I desire to establish a connection to the discovered Bluetooth Device. From the official documentation here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/connect-bluetooth-devices, it says that I need not worry if the device was previously paired or not as the android operating system will auto initiate the pairing process once I call this method `BluetoothSocket.Connect`. The app is working fine in the discovery process as it returns populates my ListView object with the names of the unknown discoverable bluetooth devices in range. The `Bluetooth.Connect()` consumes a lot of processing power in the main thread and I  had to extend the Thread class and implement my Bluetooth Connect method inside the `Run` method of that class. The code is Android Java made to work from C# through the use of Xamarin Bindings.
Below is what the log cat displays when I click on the device name on the ListView

```
BluetoothClient D/BluetoothUtils: isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy start : device null
BluetoothClient I/BluetoothSocket: connect() for device 74C17D called by pid: 23141
BluetoothClient W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
```

After searching on the site I managed to discover that the UUID I was using was wrong and I needed to use the device to get a list of supported UUIDs. The errors on the logcat have been cleared from above to below

```
BluetoothClient.BluetoothClient I/BluetoothAdapter: cancelDiscovery
BluetoothClient.BluetoothClient I/BluetoothAdapter: cancelDiscovery = false
```

The code am using to connect to the discovered devices is below

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
      protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState); 
            //listview below holds the friendly names of the discovered devices
            _deviceList = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.mylist);
             //handle click when user taps on a bluetooth device name
            _deviceList.ItemClick += (o, e) =>
            {
                //initialize a nul bluetooth device
                BluetoothDevice _mydevice=null;
                //read the name of the device from the tapped item
                string name = (string)_deviceList.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position);
                //iterate through all our bluetooth devices and compare name
                foreach (var device in _bluetoothDevices)
                {
                    if (device.Name == name)
                    {
                        //that is our device grab it and break out of the loop
                        _mydevice = device;
                        Log.Info("MainActivity", device.Name);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (_mydevice != null)
                {
                    //create a bluetooth socket using the
                    try
                    {
                        //use a new thread to avoid app hanging from skipping too many frames

                        BluetoothThread thread = new BluetoothThread(_mydevice,this);
                        thread.Run();
                        
                    }
                    catch (Exception m)
                    {
                        Toast.MakeText(this,m.Message,ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    }
                }
                
            };
        }
    }
//this class is for multitasking to help the app process Bluetooth requests
 public class BluetoothThread : Thread
        {
            private BluetoothDevice dev;

            private Context ctx;
            //declare default ctor
            public BluetoothThread()
            {
                
            }
            //declare the custom ctor and require context object for toasting to user 
            
            public BluetoothThread(BluetoothDevice device,Context context)
            {
                dev = device;
                ctx = context;
            }
            public override void Run()
            {
                //here you run attempt to connect to the bluetooth device using a new thread
                try
                {
                    //calling this creates another thread for helping the app with multitaskinf
                    Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                           ParcelUuid[] parcelUuids = dev.GetUuids();
                           BluetoothSocket socket = dev.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.FromString(parcelUuids[0].ToString()));
                        socket.Connect();
                    });
                   
                }
                catch (Exception p)
                {
                 Toast.MakeText(ctx,p.Message,ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }
            }
        }
```

I expected my app to request the remote device for a pairing request when I called `socket.Connect()` but nothing happens in my app and I get only the logcat information above, help me make this attempt to connect to a remote device start a pairing request Thank You.